# MySQL view returns more results with an AND?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, boolean-logic

When I do this:

```
select * from vw_active_employees where division IS NULL; --319 results
```

Makes sense. And, then I do this...

```
select * from vw_active_employees where division IS NULL AND udds IS NULL; -- over 1000 results
```

Whaaaaat?? MORE results??

So, I had to wrap the view as a subselect for it to return what I was expecting. Like this:

```
select vw_active_employees.* from (select * from vw_active_employees) tmp where division IS NULL AND udds IS NULL; --317 results
```

Can someone explain this? I've never had to do this in MS SQLSERVER - so this is foreign to me.

---

---

The SQL used to create this view actually joins a number of other views together. I'm not entirely sure it's helpful to see, but you asked for it :) It's basically

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_active_employees` AS

select 
e.*, 
`vw_employee_attributes_map`.`med_school_faculty`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`paid_clinic_faculty`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`volunteer_clinic_faculty`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`dept_vote_rights`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`emeritus`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`aoa_member`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`faculty_senate`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`faculty_senator_elect`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`faculty_senator_alt_elect`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`exec_comm_member`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`ucc`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`icc`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`va`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`uwmf`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`affiliate`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`aurora`, `vw_employee_attributes_map`.`website_searchable`,
`vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`termination_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`last_promotion_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`promotion_due_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`last_reappointment_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`reappointment_duration`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`reappointment_due_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`non_renewal_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`roster`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`payroll`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`on_probation`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`probation_complete`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`probation_notify_sent_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`probation_end_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`uw_appointment_id`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`effective_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`percent`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`end_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`continuity_status`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`guaranteed_length`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`end_reason`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`midterm_eval_received`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`final_eval_received`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`annual_eval_letter_sent`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`annual_eval_sent_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`annual_eval_received`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`annual_eval_received_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`probation_month_done`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`seniority_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`represented`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`work_schedule`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`evaluation_end_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`evaluation_month_end`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`evaluation_sent_date`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`evaluation_completed`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`hiring_pi`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`appointment_type`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`appointment_type_code`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`appointment_classified`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`termination_type`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`head`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`secretary`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`division`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`supervisor_first_name`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`supervisor_last_name`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`title`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`title_code`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`udds`, `vw_employee_current_appointment_info`.`udds_code`,
`vw_employee_current_background_info`.`visa_holder`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`visa_type`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`visa_expiration_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`license`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`license_exp_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`dea`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`dea_expiration_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`national_provider_number`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`residency_location`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`residency_end_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`fellowship_location`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`fellowship_end_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`primary_board_cert`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`primary_cert_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`specialty_board_cert`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`specialty_cert_date`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`degree_info_reports`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`healthlink_id`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`uwmf_general_ledger_id`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`uwmf_employee_id`, `vw_employee_current_background_info`.`specialty`,
`vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`hipaa_training_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`sic_training_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`background_check_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`i9_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`caregiver_applies`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`caregiver_check_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`tb_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`rubella_immunity_comfirmed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`respiratory_test_completed`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`health_link`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`access_request_uwhc`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`rn_credentialing`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`bls_cert_expiration`, `vw_employee_current_compliance_info`.`uwhc_cred_submitted`,
 `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`employee_id`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`ext_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`area_code_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`number_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`country_code_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`ext_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`area_code_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`number_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`country_code_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`address1_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`address2_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`city_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`state_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`zip_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`mail_code_office`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`address1_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`address2_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`city_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`state_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`zip_home`, `vw_employee_current_contact_info`.`email`

from employee e
left join vw_employee_attributes_map on e.id = vw_employee_attributes_map.employee_id
left join vw_employee_current_appointment_info on e.id = vw_employee_current_appointment_info.employee_id
left join vw_employee_current_background_info on e.id = vw_employee_current_background_info.employee_id
left join vw_employee_current_compliance_info on e.id = vw_employee_current_compliance_info.employee_id
left join vw_employee_current_contact_info on e.id = vw_employee_current_contact_info.employee_id
where e.active = 1
```

And the vw_employee_current_appointment_info which contains 'division' and 'udds' looks like:

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_employee_current_appointment_info` AS

select e.id as `employee_id`, 

`appointment`.`termination_date`, `appointment`.`last_promotion_date`, `appointment`.`promotion_due_date`, `appointment`.`last_reappointment_date`, `appointment`.`reappointment_duration`, `appointment`.`reappointment_due_date`, `appointment`.`non_renewal_date`, `appointment`.`roster`, `appointment`.`payroll`, `appointment`.`on_probation`, `appointment`.`probation_complete`, `appointment`.`probation_notify_sent_date`, `appointment`.`probation_end_date`, `appointment`.`uw_appointment_id`, `appointment`.`effective_date`, `appointment`.`percent`, `appointment`.`end_date`, `appointment`.`continuity_status`, `appointment`.`guaranteed_length`, `appointment`.`end_reason`, `appointment`.`midterm_eval_received`, `appointment`.`final_eval_received`, `appointment`.`annual_eval_letter_sent`, `appointment`.`annual_eval_sent_date`, `appointment`.`annual_eval_received`, `appointment`.`annual_eval_received_date`, `appointment`.`probation_month_done`, `appointment`.`seniority_date`, `appointment`.`represented`, `appointment`.`work_schedule`, `appointment`.`evaluation_end_date`, `appointment`.`evaluation_month_end`, `appointment`.`evaluation_sent_date`, `appointment`.`evaluation_completed`, `appointment`.`hiring_pi`,
`appointment_type`.`name` as `appointment_type`, `appointment_type`.`code` as `appointment_type_code`, `appointment_type`.`classified` as `appointment_classified`,
`termination`.`name` as `termination_type`,
`appointment_division`.`head`, `appointment_division`.`secretary`,
`division`.`division_name` as `division`,
`supervisor`.`first_name` as `supervisor_first_name`, `supervisor`.`last_name` as `supervisor_last_name`, 
`title`.`name` as `title`, `title`.`code` as `title_code`,
`udds`.`name` as `udds`, `udds`.`code` as `udds_code`

from employee e 
left join appointment on appointment.employee_id = e.id and appointment.primary = 1
left join appointment_type on appointment.appointment_type_id = appointment_type.id
left join termination on appointment.termination_id = termination.id
left join appointment_division on appointment_division.appointment_id = appointment.id and appointment_division.primary = 1
left join division on appointment_division.division_id = division.id
left join appointment_supervisor on appointment_supervisor.appointment_id = appointment.id and appointment_supervisor.primary = 1
left join employee supervisor on appointment_supervisor.supervisor_id = supervisor.id
left join appointment_title on appointment_title.appointment_id = appointment.id and appointment_title.primary = 1
left join title on appointment_title.title_id = title.id
left join appointment_udds on appointment_udds.appointment_id = appointment.id and appointment_udds.primary = 1
left join udds on udds.id = appointment_udds.udds_id
```

Comment: please show us the view (what query did you use to create the view vw_active_employees?)

Comment: Added the view create statements above for the pertinent views.  It seems like the 'udds is null' somehow trickles down and effects the underlying view sql, which seems wrong to me. From my understanding of views, they should be a black box with set results - and the criteria you apply shouldn't affect the underlying queries that create the view's dataset.

Comment: Manual says "IS" has higher precedence than "AND" but have you tried:
`where (division IS NULL) AND (udds IS NULL);`

Comment: Good thought MMP, but still over 1000 with that syntax. I'm confounded haha.

Comment: I wonder is something weird is happening due to `select e.*,`

Comment: Yeah the part I just cant get over is how the criteria is somehow tainting the makeup of the view itself, instead of acting solely on the dataset.

Comment: can u provide the description of the table vw_active_employees

Comment: @Vineet1982 its a view and its SQL is already in the question

Comment: @conrad-frix I want to know the column definitions and character encoding used in table

Comment: Have you analyzed the result to see what you're getting thats extra.  For example are there duplicate "employee" records in the larger result set.  This is rapidly looking like a bug.  It's allowed to modify the SQL of the view based on a query, but only for performance reasons.  It shouldn't be allowed to change the effective result set.

Comment: @ConradFrix have you tried the same SQL queries directly on the tables (e.g. rewriting the query to be the mix of the view definition and the actual query?) - are the results the same?

Comment: obviously the query doesn't have match for appointment_udds.id which makes forces to perform the 2 left join resulting in many more rows. I do know if it's bug per se but it doesn't look too weird.

Comment: You're using `division` several times without specifying an alias or anything. I would try cleaning that up

Answer (score 1):

you have used left join in your tables .when join condition is true than it has been select records those match in all tables than fetch records from left tables one by one and in this case your null condition is true and it is repeat the result set view

Answer (score -1):

You are using left joins so your base table connects to the subsequent tables even if no value exists.  However, when you begin to filter the subsequent tables you are specifying a that the subsequent table contain certain values.  In this case there are probably only 319 values in the "vw_employee_current_appointment_info" with a null in the division field.  When you add in the udds field there can be more fields that are null, because of the left join the division field is NULL by definition
So, the number of connections where "vw_employee_current_appointment_info" has udds as NULL is greater than the number of records where division is NULL, so it brings them all back.  If you try this with equal joins then the number will be 319 max.

Comment: -1 What you described makes sense if it was `OR udds IS NULL`